# What do I do if I forgot my Gmail password?

Tags: gmail, password-recovery

Do I need to contact Google if I've forgotten my Gmail password?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is just to say "I forgot my password." That will give you a link to a password change form in your **secondary inbox**. If you don't have a secondary email or phone set up, then it'll just take you to the form right away.

Answer (score 1):

Visit Google's [Forgot Password page](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery) to retrieve your password. If your password is hacked or account is locked / deleted then visit Google's [Account Recovery page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183733?hl=en).